# Why DOMNodeRemoved event works only once?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

in the web-app I'm developing I'd need to dynamically create/remove iframe elements and to catch the corresponding remove events.

This is the relevant html:

```
index.html
<main> 
  [..]
  <iframe id="iframe_id" width="700" height="650" src=""></iframe>
  <div class="theday" id="js-theday"></div>
  [..]
</main>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function closeIFrame() {
    $('#iframe_id').remove();
  }
  [..]
</script>
```

In `app.js` I'm catching the remove event sent in `closeIFrame()`

```
$('#iframe_id').on('DOMNodeRemoved', function() {

}
```

In the first run, when the iframe calls `parent.closeIFrame()`, app.js receives correctly the
`DOMNodeRemoved` and do stuffs.

At some point, I'd need to recreate the iframe element. In app.js

```
function recreate_iframe_html() {
  const target = document.querySelector('#js-theday');
  var new_iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
  new_iframe.setAttribute('id', 'iframe_id');
  new_iframe.width = 700;
  new_iframe.height = 650;
  new_iframe.src = '';
  target.parentNode.insertBefore(new_iframe, target);
}
[..]
recreate_iframe_html();
```

When the new iframe calls `parent.closeIFrame()`, the iframe is correctly removed but `app.js` does not detect the `DOMNodeRemoved` event.

Why is that?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.on('DOMNodeRemoved')` only works on the items returned by the query (that is, `#iframe_id`). It does not stick around to listen to newly created items with the same id.

You need to add another listener when creating the new iframe.